# Why is the internet speed lower when behind a router in my setup?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking

## The Setup

I've got a SB6141 cable modem connected to a NETGEAR N600 Dual Band Wi-Fi Router (WNDR3400) and am on the comcast deluxe50 business plan (50Mbps up 10Mbps down). Wifi set up is pictured [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhAWr.png).

## The speed tests

Consider the speed test results pictured [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30hVV.png).

1. The first result is when my ubuntu laptop is connected directly to the cable modem.
2. Second result is when I am on Wifi (The 2.4GHz b/g/n network).
3. The third result is when I am connected to the wifi router by an ethernet wire.

## Questions

- What explains the above?
- How can I get the full 50Mbps speed on wifi?

## Edits

- After I upgraded the firmware following a suggestion below (I used NETGEAR V1.0.0.52_20.0.60, not ddwrt), I now get full speed with the wired connection to the router. Wifi speed still sucks though.

Comment: This is an ethernet router right? Connected to the modem via ethernet right? Or is it a DSL router that you replaced your modem with? (If it's the latter it could simply be an ADSL2+ router and you need a VDSL router to get that speed)

Comment: More than just the wifi changed, it looks like the routing path changed too.  Does the speed go back up when you plug it back into your laptop directly?

Comment: Retry all three tests until you get the same IP address for each of them, six times in a row (very rapidly); let's try and recude the chances of ComCast doing rate limiting or other environmental factors changing.

Comment: He wont get that without mac spoofig @Anti-weakpasswords

Comment: There could also be the problem where everyone is on the node you are using so you arent getting the bandwidth you are paying for i know at times my 130mb connection only gets 60 or so sometimes less at peak times.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin That's not it - the results show that I am getting full speed when connected to the modem directly via an ethernet cable.

Comment: My bad.  I meant to ask that.  Why don't you flash that router with ddwrt?  Then you could tweak it a little more I had the router you mentioned flashed I could get solid speeds. Do you have another router to test if it is indeed the router?

Comment: @Cestarian - yes ethernet cable. My modem is not a DSL router.

 Anti-weakpasswords - It's nigh impossible to get the same IP address in each case: when connected to the wireless router, it assigns the IP address having taken the IP address one gets from Comcast for itself.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Thanks for the suggestion! After I upgraded the firmware (I used NETGEAR V1.0.0.52_20.0.60, not  ddwrt), I now get full speed with the wired connection to the router. Wifi speed still sucks though.

Answer (score 0):

The 3400 is quite old but has been reported to be able to saturate its 100Mb port WAN to LAN so it should be working.

The most likely solution is a poor length of cable either between modem and router or router and PC. Wireless performance on 2.4Ghz can be quite low so result #2 is of little consequence.

If you try new cables and it does not work the next culprit is the router itself.

Comment: Just checked the ethernet cable I used when connecting with the router - It's all right (it's delivering full speed when connected to the modem)

Comment: Length of cable doesn't cause this much bandwidth loss (unless you're stretching it across a whole street, at least)

Comment: @Cestarian Bad lengths certainly can, even on short runs.

Comment: Dunno, I have a pretty damn long line stretching across my entire apartment, and I'm still getting a full speed of 95mbps (out of 100, not getting 100 because of the wire distance from the router to the station, but close enough), I think it was like an 8m ethernet line, I doubt he has anything longer than that, and since I'm still getting full speed, I bet it'd take something quite a bit longer to really drop the speed even by just 10%, much more for 50%, maybe a 50m line?

Comment: I mean I'm literally getting better speeds (and latency) on my 8m cable than my standard 1m cable on tests sometimes, so like I said, unless you're stretching it across the street, or throughout a whole mansion or apartment complex, it probably won't have much of an effect (certainly not from router to computer)

Comment: @Cestarian Personal anecdotes are poor proof. The fact is its common to see cheap cables sold online as "CAT5" that are actually aluminum junk that sometimes don't even manage 10/100. Just because your cable is to spec doesnt mean somebody else hasn't cut corners or even just accidentally pinched a cable.